# CodeCov cannot find reports

Tags: java, gradle, jacoco, codecov

I am trying to get codecov to run and process the reports generated by Jacoco for my multibuild Java Gradle project. However, when I run the codecov script (`bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)`), I get the following output:

```
x> No CI provider detected.
    Testing inside Docker? http://docs.codecov.io/docs/testing-with-docker
    Testing with Tox? https://docs.codecov.io/docs/python#section-testing-with-tox
    project root: .
    Yaml found at: .codecov.yml
==> Running gcov in . (disable via -X gcov)
==> Python coveragepy not found
==> Searching for coverage reports in:
    + .
--> No coverage report found.
    Please visit http://docs.codecov.io/docs/supported-languages
```

I have verified that the reports are created by jacoco in `build/reports/jacoco/codeCoverageReport`, and that the xml report in fact exists.

I setup the jacoco reporting following the guide [here (Github)](https://github.com/codecov/example-gradle). The main difference between my gradle code and the code on that github is I have `xml.destination "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/report.xml"` excluded, because Gradle will fail to process with it included.

**.codecov.yml**

```
codecov:
  require_ci_to_pass: true

coverage:
  precision: 3
  round: up
  range: "70...100"

  status:
    project: true
    patch: yes
    changes: no

parsers:
  gcov:
    branch_detection:
      conditional: yes
      loop: yes
      method: yes
      macro: no

comment:
  layout: "reach,diff,flags,tree"
  behavior: default
  require_changes: false
```

Answer (score 8):

I figured it out. Running `bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash) -h` listed the options available to me, where I found out that there is a `-f <file>` option to specify the exact file to use.

From here, I simply use that in my travis file to get it to upload correctly:

`bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash) -f build/reports/jacoco/codeCoverageReport/codeCoverageReport.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I am using maven with java15

add into pom.xml (under build section):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

add into .travis.yml:

```
script:
   - mvn clean package

after_success:
   - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
```

Worked well for me.